# What is the meaning of footloose in the business context?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of footloose in the business context? I've looked at many different meanings but I can't find the right one

Comment: Can you give us more context, like a sentence where you saw it?

Comment: from Google; '(of a commercial, industrial, or financial operation) unrestricted in its location or field of operations and able to respond to fluctuations in the market.'

Answer (score 1):

From google's definition:

> Footloose: (of a commercial, industrial, or financial operation) unrestricted in its location or field of operations and able to respond to fluctuations in the market.
>   "modern factories are largely footloose"